# Linq initialize object

Tags: linq

I have the following linq:

```
  var recprec = (from rc in db.tblTrucks
                 where rc.ID == recid 
                 select rc                
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I intialize recprec and then fill it in late. For example with a string we can do something like String xyz and then use that string later.
I need to do the same with var recprec.
I tried doing

```
     Object recprec = null;

   recprec = (from rc in db.tblTrucks
              where rc.ID == recid 
              select rc                
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am doing this as I need to use recprec in a number of different places in my program. If I keep it as var recprec... it goes out of scope so like to declare it at top where it is in scope througout my program.

Comment: Not sure what you want here, FirstOrDefault evaluates the expression to a single record (Truck?) and you can store that just as you do a string. Do you mean you want to store the expression instead of the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, your LINQ query will return whatever `tblTrucks` contains. If it's a `DataTable`, your query will return a single `DataRow`. If it's a `List<Truck>`, it'll return a single `Truck`. You just have to know what's contained within the collection you're querying.